# update row in jsf2 primefaces and hibernate is not updating in database

Tags: hibernate, jsf-2, primefaces

i use primefaces to edit the row,  and works fine, but when i deploy again, the changes are not updated and i have no error in the stacktrace.I use hibernate (HQL language) to update the table in database.
[image: Edit Row]

*** Model for table Evaluacion ("modificarEvaluacion" is the method to update on db which call the service and the service call dao and onRowEdit is the event called when you click the check button)**

```
@ManagedBean(name="evaluacion")
@SessionScoped

public class Evaluacion implements Serializable{



 //getters and setters, methods to insert and delete that works fine.


public String modificarEvaluacion() {


    Evaluacion ev= new Evaluacion();

    ev.grupo.setGrupo_id(grupo.getGrupo_id());
    ev.setGrupo(grupo);
    boolean isUpdate= evaluacionBo.modificarEvaluacion(ev);
    if (isUpdate){System.out.println("OK");}
        return "";}



public boolean isEditable() {
    return editable;
}
public void setEditable(boolean editable) {
    this.editable = editable;
}



public String editAction(Evaluacion evaluacion) {

    evaluacion.setEditable(true);
    return null;
}



public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {

    try{
    this.modificarEvaluacion();
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Evaluacion modificada");

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    } catch (Exception ex){
           FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Error al modificar");

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }
}
```

*** Service Class EvaluacionBoImpl*****

```
 public boolean modificarEvaluacion(Evaluacion evaluacion){

 return  evaluacionDao.modificarEvaluacion(evaluacion);}
```

***Dao Class EvaluacionDaoImpl***

```
public class EvaluacionDaoImpl extends  HibernateDaoSupport implements EvaluacionDao,Serializable{


public boolean modificarEvaluacion(Evaluacion evaluacion) {


    boolean isUpdate=false;


     Transaction trns = null;
        Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            trns = session.beginTransaction();



            Query query=session.createQuery("UPDATE Evaluacion set nombre=:nom, fecha=:fe,grupo=:grupo_id where evaluacionId=:evaluacionId");
            query.setParameter("nom",evaluacion.getNombre());
            query.setParameter("fe",evaluacion.getFecha());
            query.setParameter("grupo_id",evaluacion.getGrupo().getGrupo_id());
            query.setParameter("evaluacionId",evaluacion.getEvaluacionId());
            int row=query.executeUpdate();
            if (row==1) {
                isUpdate=true;}

           /* session.update(evaluacion);*/
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            if (trns != null) {
                trns.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
           // session.flush();
            session.close();
        }

        return isUpdate;

}
```

*** View: Page1.xhtml***

```
     <h:body>
       <h:form>
    <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />

    </h:form>

    <h:form id="form">
       <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true"/>

   <p:dataTable id="tablaEvaluacion"  value="#{evaluacion.listaEvaluacion}" var= "p" border="1" editable="true" style="margin-bottom:20px">
       <f:facet name="header">


     Evaluaciones 


       </f:facet>

       <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{evaluacion.onRowEdit}" update=":form:msgs" />
       <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{dtEditView.onRowCancel}" update=":form:msgs" />

       <p:column headerText="Id">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{p.evaluacionId}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{p.evaluacionId}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>

       <p:column headerText="Nombre">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{p.nombre}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"> <p:inputText value="#{p.nombre}" style="width:100%" label="Nombre"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Fecha">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{p.fecha}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"> <p:inputText value="#{p.fecha}" style="width:100%" label="Fecha"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>
       <p:column headerText="Grupo">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{p.grupo.grupo_id}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{p.grupo.grupo_id}" style="width:100%" label="Grupo"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>

         <p:column headerText="Editar" style="width:32px">

          <p:rowEditor />
       </p:column>



<p:column headerText = "Eliminar">
       <p:growl id="message" showDetail="true" />
     <h:outputLabel value="Selecciona el numero de Evaluacion:"  for="txt_evid"></h:outputLabel>
            <p:inputText id="txt_evid" value="#{evaluacion.evaluacionId}" required="true"/>

    <p:commandButton  actionListener="#{evaluacion.eliminarEvaluacion}" id="iconOnly"  icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Icon Only" 
 update="message">

        <p:confirm header="Eliminar Evaluacion" message="¿Esta seguro que desea eliminar la Evaluacion?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
    </p:commandButton>

    <p:confirmDialog global="true" >
        <p:commandButton value="Aceptar" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
        <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
    </p:confirmDialog>

 </p:column>



   </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, consider the Hibernate session live in your application scope. All the changes you do are done in a temporary session til it is flushed in the real database. It seems like you missed a commit or a flush in your transaction/hibernate session. Then, when you stop the server, your session dies and all  changes (not flushed or committed) are lost.

Regards.

Comment: thanks, but i have a "commit" after transaction (in Dao Class EvaluacionDaoImpl, the last line before the catch) and a flush before close the session (i try it to comment and uncoment and it does the same thing)

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it changing the hql queries used for update located in "modificarEvaluacion" method in my Dao class, to session.merge(evaluacion), i use this documentation for reference: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html